# Error integrating ESLint with sublime

Tags: node.js, npm, sublimetext3, eslint

I am new to Node.js, npm and sublime environment and I am finding it difficult to integrate ESlint with sublime editor.

The steps which I followed is as follows:

1. Installed ESLint with command: `npm install -g eslint`
2. Installed ESLint with Sublime package control

Now getting following error in Sublime editor:

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'eslint'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\ESLint\linter.js:12:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 28):

Go to "Preferences / Package Settings / ESLint / Settings - User" in the menu bar, and enter the following (file paths may vary):

```
{
  "node_path": "/usr/local/bin",
  "node_modules_path": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules"
}
```

Here's the GitHub page: https://github.com/polygonplanet/sublime-text-eslint. Scroll down to the "Configuring ESLint" section, it's all documented there.

Answer (score 2):

If Jeremy's answer still doesn't help, make sure your **npm** folder is exposed in your environment variable.

On Windows 7, `PATH` would include something like:

```
C:\Users\<YOUR_USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

(Location: *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System\Advanced system settings\Advanced\Environment Variables\User variables...\PATH*)

Answer (score 2):

I got ESlint working for me on Sublime Text 3 and Win 7 by editing the file "Preferences -> Package Settings -> ESLint -> Settings - Default" file, inserting an additional 3rd value for the 'Config File' as you can see in the screen-shot below:

[Steps to follow for setting up ESlint on Sublime Text 3 with Win 7+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIxST.jpg)

The file code would look like this, if you don't want to see the screen-shot:

```
{ "node_path": "C:/Program Files/nodejs",
"node_modules_path": "C:/Users/<UserName>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules",
"config_file": "C:/Users/<UserName>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/debug/.eslintrc"}
```

You can further see which file formats are supported for configuration here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if this issue has been solved in the meanwhile, but there has been [a discussion](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1238) some years ago, about installing eslint globally or locally per project. As far as I understood the discussion, it is recommended to install eslint and eslint plugins locally to avoid the issue.

In order to use Eslint with Sublime, I installed eslint in my project with:

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

Furthermore I installed [SublimeLinter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/stable/index.html) and [SublimeLinter-eslint](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-eslint) to integrate the Eslint into Sublime and let it run whenever a file is saved.

Answer (score 0):

This error is what npm would throw if it doesn't find the `eslint` module.

I had the same error and I realized that it was for incorrect node_modules_path, it `"$HOME/.npm-global"` and I just change that to `"$HOME/.npm-global/bin"`(+`"/bin"`) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i encountered that issue installing: npm install -g eslint
 solved that problem in next way:

1. get known Eslint version from terminal;

   ```
   eslint -v
   ```
2. added a line to dependencies in package.json with that known eslint version

   ```
   "dependencies": {
   ...
   "eslint": "^4.19.1"
   }
   ```
3. final step : in terminal i updated all written in this package.json

   ```
   npm install
   ```